# How to Create XML output in MySQL procedure query?

Tags: mysql, xml, stored-procedures

I am trying to migrate DB2 procedure query to MySQL procedure. This the final converted procedure in MySQL .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE
   (
   INOUT CLIENT_ID BIGINT,
     OUT CONFIG XML
   )
   BEGIN
   DECLARE CP_ID BIGINT;
   DECLARE CP_NAME VARCHAR(38);
   SET (CP_ID) = (SELECT PROFILE FROM CLIENT WHERE ID=CLIENT_ID LIMIT 1);
   SET (CP_NAME) = (SELECT NAME FROM CLIENT WHERE ID=CP_ID LIMIT 1);

        SET CONFIG = (
                   XMLELEMENT(NAME "characteristic",
                   XMLATTRIBUTES('ClientInfo' AS "name"),
                   (
                     XMLELEMENT(NAME "characteristic",
                       XMLATTRIBUTES('ClientProfileData' AS "name"),                   
                      XMLELEMENT(NAME "param", XMLATTRIBUTES('isSupport' AS "name", 'false' AS "value")),
                      XMLELEMENT(NAME "param", XMLATTRIBUTES('profileId' AS "name", CP_ID AS "value"))
                           )
                    )

                )
             );
 END;
```

Here i am trying to output `XMl` data from the table . I am creating same functionality with `XMLELEMENT`,`XMLATTRIBUTES` in `DB2` . unfortunately i didn't find any alternatives in MySQL .

How can i achieve this same procedure in `MySQL` ? Any help or suggestions ?

Comment: I would just concatenate the data out with the chars that xml is famous for.  What you have above looks like over burdern procedure calls to add the <>= to the output .  IRL if you're porting now is the time think about JSON output.  I'm told its smaller output but the best part is with name like JSON it has to work awesomely with javascript.